# Read .json in template Ionic 2 and Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

Template cant read *ngFor="let git of user.ball" whats problem ???
how get array ball from json?? I am traing but its not works

my template

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'userpage'">
      <ion-card>
          <ion-card-content>``
            <ion-list no-lines>
              <ion-item *ngFor="let profile of users">
                <ion-avatar item-left>
                  <img [src]="profile.img">
                </ion-avatar>
                <h2>{{profile.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{profile.about}}</p>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
  </div>  

<!-- Баллы и Достижения -->
<div *ngSwitchCase="'info2'">
      <ion-card>
          <ion-card-content>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let git of user.ball">
              <ion-icon name='planet' item-left></ion-icon>
         {{git.name}}
              <ion-note item-right>
         {{git.score}}
              </ion-note>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
   </div>
 </div>
```

.json  This is my Api user from here i take ball array, but ionic cant read or i have mistake i dont know help pleace!!!

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "It Developer",
    "img": "/assets/img/1_kanal.png",
    "email": "example@example.ru",
    "surname": "IT app",
    "balls": "400",

     "ball": [ 
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Активность",
         "score": "100"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "Добавления Комментарии",
         "score": "150"
      },{
         "id": 3,
         "name": "Репост в Соц Сеть",
         "score": "200"
      },
      {
         "id": 4,
         "name": "Лайк",
         "score": "50"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: is it `user.ball` or `users.ball`?

Comment: i update see again

Comment: I'm still confused with my first comment.

Comment: I wont to take (ball array) from json, but its not working

Comment: that I understood but what is name of this object? is it `user` or `users`?

Comment: object is users

Comment: Then why are you using `user.ball`?

Comment: ok! say me true way how to get array from json ??

Comment: Do you have only one object in users object???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** : The answer is regarding to this shown object only. answer may vary according to your json.

Let's say

```
this.users = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "It Developer",
    "img": "/assets/img/1_kanal.png",
    "email": "example@example.ru",
    "surname": "IT app",
    "balls": "400",

     "ball": [ 
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "Активность",
         "score": "100"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "Добавления Комментарии",
         "score": "150"
      },{
         "id": 3,
         "name": "Репост в Соц Сеть",
         "score": "200"
      },
      {
         "id": 4,
         "name": "Лайк",
         "score": "50"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To access `ball array`, you should do following,

```
<div *ngFor="let git of users[0].ball">  // user[0] refers to 0th element of users array.
        {{git.id}}-{{git.name}}-{{git.scrore}}
</div>
```

**DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/WWbTRASJCuz8UMi18JP7?p=preview**

Comment: works!!!!!!!!!! thanks !!!   I have mistake copying answer!  thank you a lot!!!!!

Comment: Welcome @AccessDenied